# Behat 3 with Laravel 5: acceptance test passes but it should not

Tags: php, laravel-5, behat, mink

I'm doing my firsts acceptance tests for a Laravel 5 application using Behat 3 and Mink.

The application runs under a Homestead VM.

The test is straightforward and is located in the `features/example.feature` file. This is the test:

```
Feature: Sample

    In order to learn Behat
    As a programmer
    I need a simple url testing

    Scenario: Registration
        Given I am not logged in
        When I go to the registration form
        Then I will be automatically logged in
```

The `FeatureContext.php` has this class:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Given I am not logged in
     */
    public function iAmNotLoggedIn()
    {
        Auth::guest();
    }

    /**
     * @When I go to the registration form
     */
    public function iGoToTheRegistrationForm()
    {
       $this->visit(url('my/url'));
    }

    /**
     * @Then I will be automatically logged in
     */
    public function iWillBeAutomaticallyLoggedIn()
    {
        Auth::check();
    }
}
```

Then, when I run `behat` from the command line, I expect the test to fail because there is no `my/url` route (the `routes.php` file only has a route for `/`).

However, the test returns green, and this is what I see:

```
Feature: Sample

    In order to learn Behat
    As a programmer
    I need a simple url testing

  Scenario: Registration                   # features/example.feature:7
    Given I am not logged in               # FeatureContext::iAmNotLoggedIn()
    When I go to the registration form     # FeatureContext::iGoToTheRegistrationForm()
    Then I will be automatically logged in # FeatureContext::iWillBeAutomaticallyLoggedIn()

1 scenario (1 passed)
3 steps (3 passed)
0m0.45s (22.82Mb)
```

Of course, I'm using the `laracasts/behat-laravel-extension` package and this is the content of the `beat.yml` file:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Laracasts\Behat: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            default_session: laravel
            laravel: ~
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behat is very simple. It treats a step as failed if an exception is thrown while executing it. It treats a step as successful otherwise.

As far as I can tell from [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication), `Auth::check()` does not throw an exception if user is not authenticated. It simply returns a boolean value.

Your step should be rather implemented more like the following:

```php
    /**
     * @Then I will be automatically logged in
     */
    public function iWillBeAutomaticallyLoggedIn()
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            throw new \LogicException('User was not logged in');
        }
    }
```

Your *"I go to the registration form"* step succeeds since you don't really verify if the page you visited is the one you expected to load. Again, you should throw an exception if a page you visited is not the right one.

Comment: I agree about the `Auth::check()`, no exception is thrown there, so Behat doesn't fail. I'm in trouble with the `iGoToTheRegistrationForm()` method, because Laravel actually _throws_ an exception when I visit the `my/url` page, since that page does not exists

Comment: Laravel might be throwing an exception, but that results in an error page being rendered. No exception is thrown withing you step.

Comment: In other words you need to still make sure the page you actually visited is not an error page.

Comment: So, I should use something like `PHPUnit::assertTrue(Auth::check())` to throw and exception when I'm not logged in? Similarly, when I visit the `my/url` page, I should do something like `if ($this->getStatusCode() == 404) { throw new Exception(); }`. Am I right?

Comment: Precisely. Assuming you have all those methods ;)